# Riemann-Roch without denominators?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-k-theory

The Riemann-Roch Theorem, the Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch Theorem , the Grothendieck-Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch Theorem , all of them are well explained at Wikipedia .I would like to understand the meaning of the "Riemann-Roch without denominators". Who first established such a theorem ? What was the motive ?

Comment: This doesn't look like a research question...

Answer (score 9):

## Some History

I believe the theorem was formulated by Grothendeick, Theorie des intersections et theoreme de Riemann-Roch. Seminaire de geometrie algebrique du Bois-Marie 1966/67 (SGA 6), Lect. Notes Math. 225, Springer-Verlag, Berlin-Heidelberg-New York (1971), Expose XIV, (3.1), p. 670. It was proved by Jouanolou in Jouanolou, J.-P., Riemann-Roch sans denominateurs. (French) Invent. Math. 11, (1970) 15-26. In Gillet, H., Riemann-Roch theorems for higher algebraic K-theory. Adv. Math. 40, (1981) 203-289., Gillet extended it , but kept the name, to the Chern class maps for the higher algebraic K-groups with values in cohomology theories satisfying certain axioms.

## Meaning of the ''Riemann-Roch without denominators''

Roughly, the following is what the Riemann-Roch theorem without denominators means (from O. B. Podkopaev, E. K. Shinder, *On the Riemann–Roch Theorem Without Denominators*, St. Petersburg Math. J., 6 Vol. 18 (2007), No. 6, Pages 1021–1027):

> The Riemann–Roch formula without denominators for a closed embedding $i : Y \hookrightarrow X$ of codimension $d$ expresses the Chern class $c_d(i_∗\mathcal{O}_Y)$ in terms of the class $[Y ] ∈ CH^d(X)$.

The following is the Riemann-Roch theorem without denominators:

> **Theorem:** Let $\frak X$ be a nonsingular variety over a field $\mathbb{F}$, and let $i:Y\hookrightarrow\frak X$ be a closed embedding of an irreducible subvariety $Y$, which has codimension $d$. Then, in $CH^d(\frak X)$,
> $$c_d(i_*\mathcal{O}_Y)=(-1)^{d-1}(d-1)![Y]$$

The proof is very long and hence I refer you to the paper cited above, [http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/gillet.pdf](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Eaar/papers/gillet.pdf), and W. Fulton, *Intersection Theory*, Second Edition, Springer-Verlag, 1998.

Comment: A nice and complete answer.

Comment: Dear @Sanath Devalapurkar: To write bold text, you can use markdown as follows: `**bold text**` produces **bold text**. To produce headers, you can use `# header` or `## header` or `### header`. Mathjax `$...$` code is not meant to format text.

Comment: @RicardoAndrade Thanks - I will edit my answer.

Comment: The mentioned "Riemann-Roch theorem without denominators" by O. B. Podkopaev, E. K. Shinder (St. Petersburg Math. J., 6 Vol. 18 (2007), No. 6, Pages 1021–1027),could be renamed  "Riemann-Roch without Jouanolou" !

Comment: I am sorry for my uncalled (on-the-spot) reaction above.

Comment: @user62675 Does this theorem assume the subvariety $Y$ to be nonsingular? In all the versions of Riemann–Roch without denominators I saw, there is the assumption that the closed embedding is regular. What I really want to know is that is it always true that $c_j(i_*E)=0$ for $0<j<d$ when $Y$ is only a closed subvariety but may be singular. I don't find an affirmative answer to this, but the theorem you listed here seem to answer it. Could you tell me the source of your theorem?

Answer (score 6):

The theorem was conjectured by [Grothendieck](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BFb0066283) and proved by J.P. Jouanolou, [Riemann-Roch sans dénominateurs](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PPN=PPN356556735_0011&DMDID=dmdlog8) (1970). By clearing the denominators you can compute Chern classes, not just the Chern character.